# Higher order periodic interpolation (curve fitting)

Tags: numerics, interpolation, visualization

I have a list of points in 3D, and I want to get a smooth interpolation or curve fit (it is more for illustration) of these points such that the first and second derivatives at the start and end points agree. With

```
ListInterpolation[pts1, {0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> 4, PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
```

even the first derivatives do not agree.

Comment: Can you post your points somewhere, so that we can use them to compare?

Comment: I might be understanding your question correctly, but if you want to ensure a continuous derivative you will need to use the following option: `ListInterpolation[pts1, {0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> 4,PeriodicInterpolation -> True, Method -> "Spline"]`. By default `ListInterpolation` is using a Hermite interpolation which does not guarantee a continuous derivative.

Comment: Is the function with open ends or a closed loop? And as @rcollyer already said, we really need the points.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It does seem that the options `PeriodicInterpolation -> True` and `Method -> "Spline"` are incompatible, so I'll give a method for implementing a genuine *cubic* periodic spline for curves. First, let's talk about parametrizing the curve.

Eugene Lee, in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1), introduced what is known as *centripetal parametrization* that can be used when one wants to interpolate across an arbitrary curve in $\mathbb R^n$. Here's a *Mathematica* implementation of his method:

```
parametrizeCurve[pts_List, a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ] := 
           FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]]
```

The default setting of the second parameter for `parametrizeCurve[]` gives the centripetal parametrization. Other popular settings include `a == 0` (uniform parametrization) and `a == 1` (*chord length parametrization*).

Now we turn to generating the derivatives needed for periodic cubic spline interpolation. This is done through the solution of an appropriate cyclic tridiagonal system, for which the functions `LinearSolve[]`, `SparseArray[]`, and `Band[]` come in handy:

```
periodicSplineSlopes[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{n = Length[pts], dy, ha, xa, ya}, {xa, ya} = Transpose[pts];
        ha = {##, #1} & @@ Differences[xa];
        dy = ({##, #1} & @@ Differences[ya])/ha;
        dy = LinearSolve[SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Drop[ha, 2], 
                                      Band[{1, 1}] -> ListConvolve[{2, 2}, ha], 
                                      Band[{1, 2}] -> Drop[ha, -2],
                                      {1, n - 1} -> ha[[2]], {n - 1, 1} -> ha[[-2]]}], 
                         3 MapThread[Dot[#1, Reverse[#2]] &,
                                     Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ {ha, dy}]];
        Prepend[dy, Last[dy]]]
```

Using Sjoerd's example:

```
sc = Table[{Sin[t], Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/5}] // N;
tvals = parametrizeCurve[sc]
   {0, 0.102805, 0.196242, 0.303758, 0.397195, 0.5, 0.602805, 0.696242,
    0.803758, 0.897195, 1.}

cmps = Transpose[sc];
slopes = periodicSplineSlopes[Transpose[{tvals, #}]] & /@ cmps;
{f1, f2, f3} = MapThread[Interpolation[Transpose[{List /@ tvals, #1, #2}], 
                                       InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Hermite",
                                       PeriodicInterpolation -> True] &,
                         {cmps, slopes}];
```

Plot the space curve:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{f1[u], f2[u], f3[u]}, {u, 0, 1}],
     Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[sc]}]]
```

[image: interpolated space curve]

Individually plotting the components and their respective derivatives verify that the interpolating functions are $C^2$, as expected of a cubic spline:

[image: plots of components and derivatives]

Comment: amazing!!! Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You are talking about a list of 3D points and curve fitting. I therefore assume you want a function with a single parameter that describes a curve fitting through your set of points. I don't believe `ListInterpolate` can handle that.

My alternative is the following.

First, a set of 3D points:

```
pts1 = Table[{Sin[t], Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/5}] // N;
```

I get incomprehensible errors (*Interpolation::mspl: The Spline method could not be used because the data could not be coerced to machine real numbers*) if I interpolate using the "Spline" method combined with `PeriodicInterpolation`. I therefore add the 2nd and 3rd point to the end of the array (the last and first one were already the same). This ensures a smooth connection of beginning and end of the list:

```
pts2 = Join[pts1, pts1[[2 ;; 3]]];
```

I now interpolate through each dimension separately:

```
f = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder->3, Method->"Spline"] & /@Transpose[pts2]
```

Plot the result:

```
p = Show[
      ParametricPlot3D[Through[f[x]], {x, 1, Length[pts1]}, Axes -> None],
      Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point@pts1}]
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: You are defining `pts2` but you are not using it.

Comment: Showing the data points on the same plot would visually help ;-)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Something like the above?

Comment: @Matariki Copied the wrong version. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Haha, yes, very neat :) +1

Comment: Looks good. I looked at it for too long. I am dizzy now. :) +1

Comment: Very simple and easily genelarisable to more dimensions (maybe not the graph though :P)