# Dual complex integral over implicit path using contour plot

Tags: graphics, numerics, complex, calculus-and-analysis

**Context**

I am interested in doing double contour integral over paths which are defined implicitly.
For the sake of debugging, let's assume its
$$\oint_{\cal C}\oint_{\cal C} \frac{1}{u\, x} d u d x$$ 
where $\cal C$ is defined implicitly as the zero of a function (here for instance
$x^4+y^4- x y/2=1$).

I would like to make use of the `ContourPlot` function of *Mathematica* to extract the contour path for me.
(The motivation is to implement the so called "saddle point method" in the complex plane while integrating over contours of null imaginary part of some given function)

**Question**

> How to extract smooth enough contours to not mess up the double complex integral?

**Attempt**

I first extract the path

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 - 1/2 x y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25];
dat = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]] // Chop // Rest // Transpose;
dat = GaussianFilter[#, 0] & /@ dat;nn = Length[dat[[1]]];rg = (Range[nn] - 1.)/(nn - 1);
dat = Transpose /@ Partition[Riffle[{rg, rg}, dat], 2];
path = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ dat;
path = Function[t, path[[1]][t] + I path[[2]][t] // Release];
```

(ignore the `GaussianFilter` for now) which looks like this

```
{ParametricPlot[path[t] // {Re[#], Im[#]} & // Release, {t, 0, 1},ImageSize -> 200],
Plot[path[t] // {Re[#], Im[#]} & // Release, {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200]} // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For reference let us also define an explicit (circular) path

```
path0[t_] = Exp[2 Pi I t];
```

Let's now start with a simple contour integration in the complex plane,
using `NContourIntegrate` defined by

```
   NContourIntegrate[f_, par : (z_ -> g_), {t_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   NIntegrate[Evaluate[D[g, t] (f /. par) /. t -> t1], {t1, a, b},opts]
```

:

```
NContourIntegrate[1/x, x -> path0[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // Chop
NContourIntegrate[1/x, x -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // Chop

(* 0. +6.28319 I -0.00291648-6.27423 I *)
```

(the negative $2\pi\imath$ reflects a wrong orientation of the implicit path which is not 
relevant to my problem).

Now moving on to double integration, first with the explicit path (where I divide the answer by the expected answer $(2 \imath \pi)^2$)

```
 Clear[h]; h[u_?NumberQ] := NContourIntegrate[1/x/u, x -> path0[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]; 
NContourIntegrate[h[u], u -> path0[t], {t, 0, 1},PrecisionGoal -> 3]/(2 I Pi)^2 // Chop

 (* 1.*)
```

and finally for the implicit path

```
Clear[h]; h[u_?NumberQ] := NContourIntegrate[1/x/u, x -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
NContourIntegrate[h[u], u -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]/(2 I Pi)^2 // Chop

 (* 1.53254 +0.00796458 I *)
```

which is a terrible answer!

Now in the code above I replace the useless command `dat = GaussianFilter[#, 0] & /@ dat;`
by

```
dat = GaussianFilter[#, 4] & /@ dat;
```

I get

```
 (* 1.00097 +0.00168785 I *)
```

which is better.

I strongly suspect that the problem lies with 
the contour extraction which produces  dat containing duplicates such as
{{-1.,  0}
{-1.,   0}
{-1.,   0}
{-1.,   0}
{-0.990251, 0.0735841}
{-0.988311, 0.0833333}
{-0.987415, 0.0959183}}
which in turn as suppressed by the Gaussian filtering.

Indeed, while the contour itself seems unaffected, its components in red and pink are less jaggy:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and this apparently small amount of noise (and/or duplicates) completely mess up the integral.

> Is it possible to tweak the `ContourPlot` routine or its output to avoid duplicates and get good accuracy on this type of integrals?

**EDIT**

The improvement involved with the `GaussianFilter` is actually critical because if I extend this problem to a triple integral,
$$\oint_{\cal C}\oint_{\cal C}\oint_{\cal C} \frac{1}{u \,v\, x } d u d v d x$$ 
 via

```
Clear[h1]; h1[u_?NumberQ, v_?NumberQ] := NContourIntegrate[1/(x u v), x -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}];
Clear[h2]; h2[v_?NumberQ] := NContourIntegrate[h1[u, v], u -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}]
NContourIntegrate[h2[v], v -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}]/( 2I Pi)^3
```

I get

```
(* -0.975052-0.00767858 I *)
```

compared to

```
(* -2.91536 -0.040382 I *)
```

without!

**EDIT 2**

To be more specific about the core of the problem, this curve is too jaggy:

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 - 1/2 x y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25];
dat = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]] // Chop // Rest // Transpose;
dat = GaussianFilter[#, 0.] & /@ dat;nn = Length[dat[[1]]];rg = (Range[nn] - 1.)/(nn - 1);
dat = Transpose /@ Partition[Riffle[{rg, rg}, dat], 2];dat[[1]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can make it less jaggy by changing the option to `PlotPoints -> 125` but it actually makes the contour integration worse!

Comment: If you take the `Evaluate` out of your definition of `NContourIntegrate` you get the right answer (albeit slowly).  Someone wiser than me will have to explain why though.  For speed during experimentation, may I suggest you interpolate a triangle as your contour.

Comment: You might want to try using `DeleteDuplicates[]` on the points obtained from `ContourPlot[]`, and then use *[centripetal parametrization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10277)* for constructing the `InterpolatingFunction[]`. I seem to get slightly better results with this filigree...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the same symbol `t1` is used in the `NIntegrate` call within `NContourIntegrate`.  When more than one `NContourIntegrate` are nested, each uses the same symbol `t1`, which means in the innermost integral, all the variables have been replaced by `t1`.  *[Edit: More accurately, the outer integral effectively blocks `t1` and replaces it by a numerical value, so that all the replacements `t -> t1` in the inner integral(s) replace the symbol represented by `t` by the same numerical value.]*  Hence the integral does not calculate what was intended.  Localizing `t1` in `Module` is a solution.

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 - 1/2 x y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25];
dat = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]] (*//Rest*) //  Transpose;
dat = GaussianFilter[#, 0] & /@ dat;
nn = Length[dat[[1]]]; rg = (Range[nn] - 1.)/(nn - 1);
dat = Transpose /@ Partition[Riffle[{rg, rg}, dat], 2];
path = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ dat;
path = Function[t, path[[1]][t] + I path[[2]][t] // Release];

Clear[NContourIntegrate];
NContourIntegrate[f_, par : (z_ -> g_), {t_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{t1}, 
  NIntegrate[Evaluate[D[g, t] (f /. par) /. t -> t1], {t1, a, b}, opts]]
```

The integration works, but it is slow.

```
Clear[h]; 
h[u_?NumberQ] := NContourIntegrate[1/x/u, x -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
NContourIntegrate[h[u], u -> path[t], {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]/(2 I Pi)^2 //
   Chop // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1800.94, 1.}  *)
```

One can directly do the path integral in `NIntegrate` without the piecewise linear parametrization, and it's a bit faster.

```
Clear[h];
pts = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]].{1, I};
h[u_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[1/x/u, Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ pts}, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
NIntegrate[h[u], Evaluate@{u, Sequence @@ pts}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]/(2 I Pi)^2 //
   Chop // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {682.515, 1.}  *)
```

With fewer points, it is much faster still.  As long as the integrand is meromorphic and the original and new paths of integration do not contain a pole of the integrand, then the results will be the same.

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 - 1/2 x y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 0];
pts = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]].{1, I};
NIntegrate[1/x/u, Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ pts}, Evaluate@{u, Sequence @@ pts},
  PrecisionGoal -> 3]/(2 I Pi)^2 // Chop // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.555472, 1.}  *)
```

Note: The OP's original code used `Rest`, which resulted in a path that wasn't closed.  This introduces a slight error in the integral which can be avoided by omitting `Rest`.

This works also with triple integrals

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 - 1/2 x y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0];
pts = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]].{1, I};
NIntegrate[1/x/u/v, Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ pts}, 
    Evaluate@{u, Sequence @@ pts},
    Evaluate@{v, Sequence @@ pts}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]/(2 I Pi)^3 // 
  Chop // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {19.964775,-1.}  *)
```

Comment: Very nicely spotted! I had wrongly convinced myself this was a fundamental problem, not a bug.

Comment: Do you understand the -1 in the triple integral case?

Comment: @chris I think in general the answer is `(-1)^n`, where `n` is the dimension. The `-1` because the path is clockwise instead of counterclockwise (which I think you referred to in the Q).