# Integrate over implicit 1D region: works for algebraic but not transcendental equation?

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, implicit

**QUESTION**

How come  this works:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[{x == y^3, x <= 1, x >= 0}, {x, y}]]
```

But this fails:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[{Sin[Pi x] == y, x <= 1, x >= 0}, {x, y}]]
```

where we have

```
ContourPlot[x == y^3, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
ContourPlot[Sin[Pi x] == y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A related question is [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13798/1089)

Comment: Thinking that `Sin[Pi x] == y` might be failing because its inverse is multivalued, I tried `Exp[x] == y`, but it also fails.  Yet, `Abs[x - .5] == Sqrt[y]` works fine, giving the same answer as `(x - .5)^2 == y`, as it should.

Comment: @bbgodfrey good point, but on the other hand it is not on the interval I am considering.

Comment: Could it be because it can't figure out the dimension of the region?  `RegionDimension[
 ImplicitRegion[Sin[\[Pi] x] == y && x <= 1 && x >= 0, {x, y}]]` fails.  The same thing works for the first region you tried.  `NIntegrate` would need to know what this is really a 1D integral, not a 2D one, to give a reasonable (non-zero) result.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I doubt it.  If we invert the relationship using `Reduce` that problem goes away yet Mathematica still can't figure out that it's a 1D region.

Comment: I do wonder if this is a bug.  I would have thought that even discretization would require figuring out the dimension first.  It does produce a 1D-type discretized region after all.  Perhaps it's something worth reporting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{Sin[Pi x] == y, x <= 1, x >= 0}, {x, y}]
```

This is a 1D region embedded in 2D space.  `NIntegrate` needs to know this to produce a reasonable result.  My guess is that it uses `RegionDimension`, which fails here:

```
In[41]:= RegionDimension[reg]

During evaluation of In[41]:= RegionDimension::nmet: Unable to compute the dimension of region ImplicitRegion[Sin[π x]==y&&x<=1&&x>=0,{x,y}]. >>

Out[41]= RegionDimension[
 ImplicitRegion[Sin[π x] == y && x <= 1 && x >= 0, {x, y}]]
```

`RegionMeasure` would be equivalent to your `NIntegrate` example in this specific case and it also fails.

Mathematica can determine the dimension of the other region just fine:

```
RegionDimension@
 ImplicitRegion[{x == y^3, x <= 1, x >= 0}, {x, y}]
(* 1 *)
```

We could however discretize the region first:

```
In[42]:= dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg]

In[43]:= RegionDimension[dreg]
Out[43]= 1

In[44]:= RegionMeasure[dreg]
Out[44]= 2.30414

In[45]:= NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ dreg]
Out[45]= 2.30414
```

This works, but the problem is that at the discretization step we lose precision that `NIntegrate` can never re-gain afterwards.

`DiscretizeRegion` has several options which can control how and how accurately the discretization is done.  I'm not sure which one is the best choice in this case, but `MaxCellMeasure` would be one.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize you could discretize also 1D regions. That should do the trick for my problem.

Comment: @chris Just keep in mind that the accuracy of the discretization can have a significant effect on the result of the integral.