# Is it possible to write a MMA version of LineInt like Maple?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I asked this question I found that the available answers relied heavily on the official `RegionConvert`, but which is very weak at that time. Now, We have a more powerful [`RegionConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionConvert.html) in [version 13](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/), so I expect to update the current answer to this question with a bonus

---

I know there's no direct method to do line integrals in *Mathematica* as of 2021. But we now have more mature `Region` schemes, and that makes it very easy to compute multiple integrals like:

```
Integrate[f,{x,y,...}∈reg]]
```

I have to say this is a very elegant solution. But we still don't seem to be able to do anything about vector integrals (type II curve integrals). Let's see some examples about `LineInt` from [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/) documentation：

```
LineInt(VectorField((x, y)), Line((1, 2), (3, -4)))
```

> `10`

```
LineInt(VectorField((x, y)), LineSegments((0, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)))
```

> `1`

```
LineInt(VectorField((4*y^3, -2*x^2)), LineSegments((-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)))
```

> `-16`

```
LineInt(VectorField((y, -x, z)), Circle3D((0, 0, 0), r, (1, 1, 1)))
```

> $-\frac{2 \sqrt{3}r^2 \pi}{3}$

Amazing!! Is it possible to write a *Mathematica* version of `LineInt` like this?

Comment: Yes, indeed you can do it, since ``Integrate`` supports ``Region`` primitives.

Comment: ＠E. Chan-López Could you post an answer to try?

Comment: Other commands of [Vector Calculus](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/MapleSim/view.aspx?path=VectorCalculus%2fDetails)  also deserve attention.

Comment: @yode I am trying to build a function for the case of multiple line segments, but cannot complete it yet. I'll upload something in case I make it.

Comment: @yode Check out my first approximation of the problem. I think we should review more functions in Maple's VectorCalculus package.

Comment: This might be of interest https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13798/1089

Comment: Since version 10 Mathematica offers: [integrate over regions](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/symbolic-geometry/integrate-over-regions.html) that is further improved in version 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, `LineIntegrate` is introduced in *v13.3*. Let's solve the problems you've mentioned:

```
LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ Line@{{1, 2}, {3, -4}}]
(* 10 *)
```

[image]

```
LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ Line@{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}}]
(* 1 *)
```

[image]

```
LineIntegrate[{4 y^3, -2 x^2}, {x, y} ∈ 
  Line@{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]
(* -16 *)
```

[image]

For 4th problem, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `Circle3D` at the moment, but it's not hard to create our own:

```
nsol = {1, 1, 1}/Sqrt[3];

usol = {x, y, z} /. 
   First@FindInstance[nsol . {x, y, z} == 0 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}];

preg = 
  With[{n = nsol, u = usol, o = {0, 0, 0}}, r Cos[t] u + r Sin[t] n\[Cross]u + o]

LineIntegrate[{y, -x, z}, {x, y, z} ∈ ParametricRegion[preg, {{t, 0, 2 Pi}}]]
(* -((2 π r^2)/Sqrt[3]) *)
```

[image]

Comment: `Circle3D` is a little ugly :)

Comment: @yode Sadly the three new-in-13.3 integral related functions don't seem to be good at handling `ImplicitRegion`, at least for now…

Answer (score 30):

In many cases, yes! As a start, we'll restrict ourselves for now to symbolic/exact regions and won't concern ourselves with discretizing regions for numerical integrations (though this is possible).

#### Parametric Regions

We'll begin by noticing that `RegionConvert` can give us a parametric representation of many regions. For example,

```
RegionConvert[Circle[], "Parametric"]

(* Out: *)

(* ParametricRegion[{{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, {x}] *)
```

(Those `x`'s are actually `\[FormalX]`s, by the way, but that would just clutter this explanation up.)

Our strategy for parametric regions will simply be to get the tangent information of our region from that function. (It would be nice if Mathematica had built-in ways to extract tangent info—there's a lot of potential for differential geometry here.)

#### Implicit Regions

We can also tackle implicit regions! This is the (only) other capability of `RegionConvert`: to convert a region to `ImplicitRegion` form.

There's a fundamental piece of missing information needed for integrating over Mathematica's regions: orientation. Currently, the sign can't be guaranteed one way or the other for parametric regions. (I'm considering changing the functionality so that you always get a positive answer. More on this issue later.) For implicit regions we face the same obstacle. The best we can do is $\int_{\vec{\gamma}} |\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{\gamma}|$.

That disclaimed, here's our strategy:

- Put the defining constraint in disjunctive normal form with `BooleanConvert`.
- Separate the disjuncts from each other to be added together later. (Potential issue: overlapping conditions.)
- Look at the regions defined by each conjunctions, and keep only the ones that are 1-dimensional (not zero-dimensional; sorry, physicists with `DiracDelta`-laden vector fields.) (Possible issue: currently we check the apparent codimension given by equality count. Perhaps we should instead be turning these back into regions and using the built-in `RegionDimension`.)
- Extract the equalit(y/ies) from the conjunction; subtract one side from the other to obtain a list of $n-1$ functions which specify the curve as their mutual zero set ($n$ the embedding dimension)
- Look at the gradients of these functions and use those to "project off" components of our vector field at each point until only the part pointing along the curve remains.
- Integrate the norm of those vectors over the region.
- Add together the resulting integrals.

#### Multi-segment lines

Also, I figured it would be nice to check for `Line` regions first, and handle them separately. After all, these are fairly unambiguously directed! For some reason, `RegionConvert` doesn't like converting them to parametric form—but that means we *definitely* lose all orientation info. Instead, I check for regions with head `Line` and homebrew the parametrizations. This lets us preserve the implicit orientation: `Line[{pt0, pt1, pt2, ...}]` should be directed from `pt0` to `pt1` to `pt2`, etc. For syntax, no change needs to be made to the input; the code will just automatically react differently to explicit `Line` regions.

#### Explicit parametrization

I've also included support for the explicit, non-region parametric form used in the other nice answer to this post! Credit to @E. Chan-López for the notion that this should be a way to specify a line integral—I was locked in thinking about regions! The syntax of mine's a bit different, though: I demand that an actual function be given as a first argument, to avoid both a vars and an iterator argument (and to avoid privileging `x`, `y`, and `z`, as that's not very kosher in Mathematica).

---

The new sections are not very well commented. I'll come back and edit them when I can.

```
(*Helper function for extracting parts of ParametricRegion:*)
ParametricRegionDestructure[
  ParametricRegion[{x_, cons_}, params_]] := {x, cons, params}

(* Helper functions for ImplicitRegions: *)
(* This could probably be more compact. *)

ImplicitRegionDestructure[
  ImplicitRegion[cond_, params_]] := {ExtractJuncts[cond], params}
ExtractDisjuncts[HoldPattern[Or[x__]]] := {x}
ExtractDisjuncts[x : Except[_Or]] := {x}
ExtractConjuncts[HoldPattern[And[x__]]] := {x}
ExtractConjuncts[x : Except[_And]] := {x}
ExtractJuncts[cond_] := 
 ExtractConjuncts /@ ExtractDisjuncts[BooleanConvert[cond]]
ApparentCodim[conjunctList_] := Count[conjunctList, _Equal]
FilterJunctsByCodim[disjunctList_, codim_] := 
 Select[disjunctList, ApparentCodim[#] == codim &]
ConjunctsToGrads[conjunctList_, params_] := 
 Cases[conjunctList, x_ == y_ :> Grad[x - y, params]]
ProjectOff[vf_, nv_] := Simplify[vf - nv (vf . nv/(nv . nv))]
ProjectOffAll[vf_, nvs_] := Fold[ProjectOff, vf, nvs]

(* Helper functions for lines: *)

LineDestructure[x : HoldPattern[Line[{{__} ..}, {{__} ..} ..]]] := 
 Flatten[(LineDestructure@*Line /@ (List @@ x)), 1]
LineDestructure[HoldPattern[Line[x : {{__} ..}]]] := 
 Partition[x, 2, 1]
LineSegmentToFormal[{x0 : {__}, 
   x1 : {__}}] := ((1 - \[FormalT]) x0 + \[FormalT] x1)
LineSegmentToTangent[{x0 : {__}, x1 : {__}}] := x1 - x0

(*Make it hold its arguments,and make it look like Integrate on \
input:*)

SetAttributes[LineIntegrate, HoldAll]
SyntaxInformation[LineIntegrate] = SyntaxInformation[Integrate];

LineIntegrate[v0 : {__}, Element[(vars : {__}), region_?RegionQ]] := 
 Module[{(*Vector field expression turned into a function:*)
    v = Construct[Function, Unevaluated[vars], Unevaluated[v0]],
    (*variables to hold the region:*)
    regiontype, cregion, nEmbed = RegionEmbeddingDimension[region],
    (*variables to hold the components of a parameterized region:*)
      x, cons, params,
    (*more variables to hold the components of an implicit region*)
      juncts,
    (* for lines: *)
    lines,
    (*variable to hold the tangent vector to our curve:*)
    tangentVector},
    (*The regiontype and cregion are set in the \
      Condition (/;) guarding the module expression,
      so we only ever have to compute them once.*)
   Switch[regiontype,
     "Line",
     lines = LineDestructure[cregion];
     Plus @@ 
      Table[
       With[{vf = v @@ LineSegmentToFormal[line], 
         dl = LineSegmentToTangent[line]}, 
        Integrate[vf . dl, {\[FormalT], 0, 1}]], {line, lines}],
     
     "Parametric",
     {x, cons, params} = ParametricRegionDestructure[cregion];
     tangentVector = D[x, params];
     (*Apply our vector field to points in the region (x);
     insert params into the integral syntactically*)
     With[{f = v @@ x, params0 = params}, 
      Integrate[f . tangentVector, 
       params0 \[Element] ImplicitRegion[cons, params0]]],
     
     "Implicit",
     {juncts, params} = ImplicitRegionDestructure[cregion];
     juncts = FilterJunctsByCodim[juncts, nEmbed - 1];
     With[{vf = v @@ params, params0 = params},
      Plus @@ Table[
        With[{projected = 
           ProjectOffAll[vf, ConjunctsToGrads[conjuncts, params]], 
          conjunction = And @@ conjuncts},
         
         With[{integrand = 
            Simplify[Sqrt[projected . projected], 
             params0 \[Element] Reals]},
          
          Integrate[integrand, 
           params0 \[Element] 
            ImplicitRegion[conjunction, params0]]]],
        {conjuncts, juncts}]
      ]] /;(*Check that RegionConvert succeeded;
    set variables.*)(MatchQ[
        cregion = region, _Line] && (regiontype = "Line"; True)) || 
     MatchQ[
      cregion = 
       RegionConvert[region, 
        regiontype = "Parametric"], _ParametricRegion] || 
     MatchQ[
      cregion = 
       RegionConvert[region, regiontype = "Implicit"], _ImplicitRegion]
   ] /;(*Also check that our dimensions match up.*)
  Length[Unevaluated[v0]] == Length[Unevaluated[vars]] == 
    RegionEmbeddingDimension[region] && RegionDimension[region] == 1

(* For parametrically explicit arguments: *)

LineIntegrate[v_, r : {rs___}, iterator : {t_Symbol, _, _}] := 
 Construct[Module, Unevaluated[{t}], 
  Unevaluated@Module[{dr = D[r, t]}, Integrate[v[rs] . dr, iterator]]]
```

This is just a start. There are a lot of issues:

- No way to choose orientation—except for `Line` regions or explicit parametrizations, integrals are only unique up to a sign, and you may get the opposite sign than the one you bargained for without any indication of this. We should create a new `OrientedRegion` datatype.
- When we don't have enough info for orientation, we should at least have messages for alerting the user as to what kind of integral will be taken (absolute or not). There are also arguments to be made (or had!) about whether regions that automatically get converted to parametric form should have a sign or not, and if not, *where* the sign should be set to "positive". There's a big difference between $\int_{\vec{\gamma}} |\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{\gamma}|$ and $\left|\int_{\vec{\gamma}} \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{\gamma}\right|$!
- Just realized I demand that the argument be an explicit vector field (a list). I should instead allow arbitrary expressions, like `v[x,y,z,...]` as well; this should be an easy fix when I get back.
- We put a *lot* of trust in formal variables being definitionless, and also we allow expressions like `v` and `f` to evaluate fully with those formal variables inside. (Not to mention the newly-exposed conditions in `ImplicitRegion`!) This could be risky, in part because they *might* have a definition, but mostly because parts of our given expression might evaluate to something undesirable when acting on them outside of an integral—we don't know, and don't want to risk it.
- No error messages yet; it just returns unevaluated. Ideally we should say what's wrong if we can't evaluate.
- We could generalize to higher dimensions! Why only integrate on curves? (Note that the current implementation supports any embedding dimension, by the way.)
- Options! To, e.g., specify the preferred representation of our region, or include extra assumptions in our internal `Simplify`s.
- Mathematica has access to a great curated collection of curves via `SpaceCurve`. These often come with tangent vectors included as properties! We could extend this to use those too—not just regions—but that's pretty straightforward.
- We could add support for simple-enough `BooleanRegions`.
- Numerical functionality! There's lots to be done there.

#### Tests

Here are some tests demonstrating the different functionality! (The only one from the original post that's excluded is the `Circle3D` one, as Mathematica (frustratingly) does not have a corresponding built-in for circles in 3D.)

```
(* (naturally) Parametric regions: *)
LineIntegrate[{-y, x}, {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r]]

(* Out: *)
(* 2 Pi r^2 *)

(* Naturally implicit region: *)

reg = ImplicitRegion[(a == 5 || a == 0) && 0 <= b <= 1, {a, b}];

LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] reg]

(* Out: 1 *)

(* Explicitly parametrized region: *)

LineIntegrate[{x,y} |-> {-y,x}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* Out: -2 Pi *)

(* Maple multisegment line tests: *)

LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] Line[{{1, 2}, {3, -4}}]]

LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}}]]

LineIntegrate[{4 y^3, -2 x^2}, {x, y} \[Element] 
  Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]]

(* Out: 10, 1, -16 *)
```

Comment: It's a great start. :)

Comment: Nice answer. It's a great start, thorimur.

Comment: thanks! :) @yode just updated to include a bunch more functionality. Still more work to be done, but this covers a lot more cases! :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not at all sure anyone can do this when I ask this question. At the moment it seems that the main difficulty with vector integration comes from the fact that the new function `RegionConvert` introduced in the v12.3 is too weak

Comment: @yode Well, lots of cases are taken care of—the "real" problem is that mathematica's regions are intrinsically unoriented; if we want orientation we have to resort to the special `Line` behavior (which I've made oriented) or explicit parametrization. I think a new `OrientedRegion` datatype is the next step for this functions! But besides that, are there any explicit cases you can think of that aren't taken care of by this function? The three `Line` maple cases are taken care of, and the last one can be with a custom `Circle3D`  parametrization—unfortunately Mathematica doesn't have a built-in.

Comment: Had you seen [Circumcircle3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Circumcircle3D/) ,[Circle3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Circle3D/) or [Incircle3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Incircle3D/)?

Comment: @yode No, i haven't, but those aren't built in—also, they seem to be geared towards graphical use and numerical approximations, and in the case of `Circle3D`, return a list containing a long `Line` primitive. While my function can still integrate these, because they're fundamentally approximations, the answer won't match symbolically with Maple's (only numerically). Likewise, `BSplineCurve`s are graphics primitives and not regions (see e.g. `RegionQ @ BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}}]`), and so we would not expect to integrate over them.

Comment: @yode Are there regions you're thinking of that this function doesn't handle? Especially ones that are common for line integration? (One I can think of is `BooleanRegion`, but I'm not sure how often that comes up when doing line integrals.) I'd be interested in expanding the functionality!

Comment: There is also `Geodesic`, which gives parameterised equations for geodesics on a sphere. And, functions in the #WFR are, effectively, built-in: with the forthcoming paclet repository, you will find that more and more of the “core” functionality will be provided by calls to a repository:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Geodesic/

Comment: We have a more powerful `RegionConvert` in [version 13](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/), I wonder if we can expect you to update your answer. :)

Comment: maybe! however, i don't have access to version 13 yet, and the documentation doesn't show how the new `"Mesh"` interpretation works yet. That would be the new update—I could delete the section that deals with `Line`s, but I'm not yet convinced that the parametric region version is actually better for integration (and I'm not sure yet if it preserves orientation)!

Comment: @thorimur It sounds very unpromising, but you can try it on [cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) first :)

Comment: I have made a bonus for wait you :)

Comment: oh wow, thank you very much @yode ! I really appreciate that :) Now that it's the new year maybe I'll come back to it sometime, refine it, and submit it as a `ResourceFunction`, since after a quick look I couldn't seem to see one there!

Comment: @thorimur Do `PositivelyOrientedPoints` and `NegativelyOrientedPoints` can help to ensure the line orientation?

Comment: interesting, yes, I think so! perhaps if we had the user specify that they wanted some points on the curve to be considered positively/negatively oriented under the intended orientation. that could help for closed curves!

Answer (score 14):

Another approach to this problem:

```
(*Code for simple paths*)
LineIntegrate[vectorfield_List, varsfield_List, path_List, 
varpath_, I_List] := Module[{vars, r, s1, s2, g1, g2},
vars := 
Table[ToExpression[ToString[varpath] <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 
  Length[vectorfield]}];
 r:= D[path, varpath]; 
s1:= Simplify[vectorfield /.Thread[vars -> Table[path[[i]], {i, 1, Length[path]}]]];
s2:= Simplify[vectorfield /.Thread[varsfield -> Table[path[[i]], {i, 1, Length[path]}]]];
g1:= Dot[s1, r];
g2:= Dot[s2, r];
Return[
Piecewise[{{Integrate[g1, {varpath, I[[1]], I[[2]]}], 
   Variables[vectorfield] === {}}, {Integrate[
    g2, {varpath, I[[1]], I[[2]]}], 
   Variables[vectorfield] =!= {}}}]];
];
```

Some tests for `LineIntegrate` function:

```
(*LineInt(VectorField((x, y)), Line((1, 2), (3, -4)))*)
LineIntegrate[{x, y}, {x, y}, {1 + 2 t, 2 - 6 t}, t, {0, 1}]
(*10*)

LineIntegrate[{1, 0, 3}, {x, y,z}, {3 t, 1 + 3 t, 7 + 3 t}, t, {0, 1}]
(*12*)

c[t_] := {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}
V[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x}
X = {x, y};
LineIntegrate[V[X], X, c[t], t, {0, 2 Pi}]
(*2 π r^2*)
```

`LineIntegratePiecewise` function:

```
(*Code for piecewise paths*)
LineIntegratePiecewise[vectorfield_List, varsfield_,segments_List, varpath_, interval_List] := Total[Table[LineIntegrate[vectorfield, varsfield, segments[[i]], varpath, interval], {i, 1, Length[segments]}]]
```

Some tests for `LineIntegratePiecewise` function:

```
(*LineInt(VectorField((4*y^3, -2*x^2)), LineSegments((-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)))*)
V[{x_, y_}] := {4 y^3, -2 x^2}; X = {x, y};
linesegments[t_] := {{-1 + 2 t, -1}, {1, -1 + 2 t}, {1 - 2 t, 1}, {-1, 1 - 2 t}}
LineIntegratePiecewise[V[X], X, linesegments[t], t, {0, 1}]
(*-16*)

(*LineInt(VectorField((x, y)), LineSegments((0, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)))*)
V[{x_, y_}] := {x, y} X = {x, y};
linesegments[t_] := {{t, t}, {1, 1 - 2 t}}
LineIntegratePiecewise[V[X], X, linesegments[t], t, {0, 1}]
(*1*)
```

We need to work a function to obtain parametric regions in a simple way.

Comment: It looks like we still need some official work to improve the availability of `RegionConvert`

Comment: I just finished a function that I called LineOrientedRegion, and it works great. Also, I already cleaned up the code from the first post. Soon I will upload the update.

Comment: Really? Sounds Crazy man.. :)

Comment: Yes, of course, and at the moment I am still working on it. Do we collaborate on something?

Comment: Your work is very impressive, but I'm not sure I can help.  I'm not good at math actually..

Comment: Can I expect it to update in a few days? :)

Comment: We have a more powerful `RegionConvert` in [version 13](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/), I wonder if we can expect you to update your answer. :)

Comment: I calculate a line integral according to your method. I can only calculate it in two sections with two sections of lineintegrate function code:'c[t_] := {t^2, t}
V[{x_, y_}] := {x*y, 0}
X = {x, y};
LineIntegrate[V[X], X, c[t], t, {-1, 0}]' (*2/5*)  'c[t_] := {t^2, t}
V[{x_, y_}] := {x*y, 0}
X = {x, y}; 
LineIntegrate[V[X], X, c[t], t, {0, 1}]' (*2/5*).Can we solve this problem with only one lineintegratepiecewise function? @E. Chan-López

Answer (score 7):

Note that `NIntegrate` *directly* supports *numerical* integration of line integrals. For example, with

```
f[z_]:= Cos[z]/(z - 1)^2
```

then

```
1/(2 Pi I) NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 2, 1 + I, 0, 1 - I, 2}]
```

computes the residue of `f[z]` at `z = 1` using a (rotated) rectangular contour.

Alternatively, with a change of variables,

```
1/(2 Pi I) NIntegrate[f[z] Dt[z,t] /. z -> 1 + Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2Pi}]
```

we can evaluate the integral numerically around a circular contour.

Comment: So, how to calculate a line integral like `LineInt(VectorField((x, y)), LineSegments((0, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)))`?

Comment: This works only for vector fields defined by analytical functions inside the closed contour of the integration and continuous on the contour.