# Line integral over a rectangular path

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, graphics

I have a little problem. I need to calculate an line integral of a function on a rectangular oriented closed path.
For example I define

```
f[x_,y_]:= x-2y
```

and the integral must be on a square like:

```
Integrate[f[0,y],{y,0,1}]+Integrate[f[x,1],{x,0,1}]+Integrate[f[1,y],{y,1,0}]+Integrate[f[x,0],{x,1,0}]
```

My question:
is there a simply way to define an oriented rectangular path?

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258132/is-it-possible-to-write-a-mma-version-of-lineint-like-maple

Answer (score 3):

You may use the function "Region" in 2  dimension (it also works in 1 and 3 dimensions) to specify the path in "Integrate".  Here is an example:

```
reg = Region[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]]
f[x_, y_] = x - 2 y;
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg]
```

[image]

This gives the integral along the NOT oriented path.

If you want to account for the direction, we need to trick a bit to use "Region", because "Region" does not bother about the direction. However, we may incorporate the direction into your function like e.g.:

```
f[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {x - 2 y, y == 0  || x == 1},
    {-x + 2 y, y == 1  || x == 0},
    }];
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: I think it doesent'work because I need an 'oriented' integral, so the exact result of your example will be 3 and not -2.

Comment: I suppose, like you do previously with function Line, the path is anti-clockwise.

Comment: You are right, Region does not bother about direction. But you may put the direction into the function if you want to use Region.

Comment: Yes, now it is what i meant, it works. But there is a better way to define an oriented path, without creating an oriented function instead ?

Comment: I only know the classic way:  `{D[f[x,y],x],D[f[x,y],y]}.{dx,dy}`

Answer (score 2):

> My question: is there a simply way to define an oriented rectangular path?

`RegionBoundary` is an easy way to get the boundary of a rectangle with the positive (counterclockwise) orientation:

```
RegionBoundary[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
(*  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]  *)
```

The harder part was not asked about: How to compute the integral over an oriented path?  The usual integral over an oriented path is a vector field, not a scalar field, so the question is a bit confusing.  A scalar path integral is independent of orientation.  The integral presented corresponds to the vector field `{x - 2 y, x - 2 y}`.  To compute the integral of a vector field, you have to either parametrize the path or reduce the integral to a scalar integral.  The following is a function that does the latter for a oriented path defined by `Line[{p1, p2,...}]`:

```
vfIntegrate // ClearAll;
(* integrate over a single line segment *)
vfIntegrate[vf_, i : {_, _} \[Element] Line[p_?MatrixQ]] /; 
   Length[p] == 2 := 
  Integrate[vf . Normalize@First@Differences@p, i];
(* break path integral into line segments *)
vfIntegrate[
   vf_, {x_, y_} \[Element] Line[p_?MatrixQ] /; Length[p] >= 3] :=
  Total[vfIntegrate[vf, {x, y} \[Element] Line[#]] & /@ 
    Partition[p, 2, 1]];
```

Example:

```
vfIntegrate[{x - 2 y, x - 2 y}, {x, y} \[Element] 
  RegionBoundary[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]]
(*  3  *)
```

Comment: Thaks, it is clear and it works!

Comment: Your method is very good. But I want to ask, is this integral path limited to the boundary of a closed region? What if the integral path is an unclosed directed curve? For example: integral path c[t_] := {t^2, t}, from point (1,-1) to point (1,1).
Function: V[{x_, y_}] := {x*y, 0}.  @Michael E2

Comment: @lotus2019 It works with `Line` (geometric) paths. For parametrized path perhaps you want something like this: `c[t_] := {t^2, t}; vf = {y, -x}; Integrate[vf . Dt[{x, y}, t] /. Thread[{x, y} -> c[t]], {t, 0, 1}]`. But that won't work if `c` is defined `c[t_?NumericQ]`, which is harder for several reasons; since it would seem to require numeric integration and not symbolic, it is perhaps not really an issue.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot! @Michael E2

Answer (score 1):

One may apply [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) to this end:

```
f[x_,y_]:= x-2y
Integrate[D[f[x, y], x] - D[f[x, y], y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

> `3`

Comment: It's clear such approach works for more complex closed paths too,

Comment: Yes, I think it is more clean, but there is a way or a built-in function that allow to create an oriented path without defining an oriented function instead (or using operators on thath function) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me continue the very nice answer of @MichealE2 and show how to parametrise the path from one given point to the other for all points. As Micheal says, you in fact have a vector field.

```
f[x_, y_] = {x - 2 y, x - 2 y};

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};

parp = Partition[pts, 2, 1]

pp = (#[[1]] + Subtract @@ (Reverse@#)*u) & /@ parp

ParametricPlot[pp, {u, 0, .95}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

Total[Integrate[f[Sequence @@ #]. D[#, u], {u, 0, 1}] & /@ pp]

(*   3   *)

Plot[Evaluate[f[Sequence @@ #]. D[#, u]], {u, 0, 1}] & /@ pp
```

Another example

```
f[x_, y_] = {x - 2 y, x - 2 y};

pts = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/24}];

ListPlot@pts

parp = Partition[pts, 2, 1];

pp = (#[[1]] + Subtract @@ (Reverse@#)*u) & /@ parp;

ParametricPlot[pp, {u, 0, .9}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

Total[Integrate[f[Sequence @@ #]. D[#, u], {u, 0, 1}] & /@ pp]

(*   -9 Sqrt[2] + 9 Sqrt[6]   *)

Plot[Evaluate[f[Sequence @@ #]. D[#, u]], {u, 0, 1}] & /@ pp
```