# Interpolate a curve in 3D

Tags: interpolation, parametric-functions

I have a sequence $\{(x_k, y_k, z_k)\}_{k=1}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, all points along a path represented by the function $\gamma \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$, which maps the distance along the path to a location in 3D space.

Is there any way for *Mathematica* to output an interpolation parametrized like $\gamma$, and has the sequence as a subset of its range?

Comment: Related: [Higher order periodic interpolation (curve fitting)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/higher-order-periodic-interpolation-curve-fitting), although the question is slightly different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with one [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html), if you specify the parameter values for each point.  Below I made the interpolated points correspond to equally spaced values (`Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)]`).

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 3}]]
(*
   {{0.634779, -0.777161, 0.579052},
    {0.0103853, -1.29444, -0.28947},
    {0.0948785, -1.83213, -0.497458},
    {0.495826, -2.40848, -0.000144566},
    {0.341527, -2.91349, 0.954199}}
*)

ifn = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[ifn[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I guess we should get used to the new default color scheme ;)

Comment: A better approach would be to use centripetal or chord-length parametrization on the points, since they are based on the configuration of the points themselves, as opposed to uniformly spaced values.