# Adding texture to `Tube[]`

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, textures

Continuing from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240690/regionplot3d-knotdata), I would like to `Texture` lines with thickness. I tried using the normal and the binormal from `FrenetSerretSystem` as in the accepted answer, but the following approach seemed more stuccessful.

[image]

```
g = With[{b = .1}, 
Graphics[{Red, 
 Table[Disk[{c, #[[1]]}, #[[2]]/35] & /@ 
   Thread@{Table[Sin@x, {x, -1, 1, b}], 
     Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, .25], x], {x, -1, 1, 
       b}]}, {c, -1, 1, b}]}, Background -> White, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0]];
R = 1; f[x_] := Sin[x]
w[x_] := Normalize[{1, f'[x], 0}]
u[x_] := Normalize[Cross[w[x], {0, 0, 1}]]
v[x_] := Cross[w[x], u[x]]
ParametricPlot3D[{x, f[x], 0} + R Cos[t] u[x] (1 - x/(3 Pi)) + 
  R Sin[t] v[x] (1 - x/(3 Pi)), {x, 0, 3 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[g], TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, t}, {u, t}], 
 ViewPoint -> {0.2, 4, 2}]
```

However, I would ideally like to be able to use graphics primitives. I tried with the simpler approach in `Graphics3D` but didn't get anywhere

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[g], CapForm[None], 
Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}], {.2, .1, .1, .01}]}, 
Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

I was wondering whether it was possible to feed it into `BoundaryMeshRegion[]` (as in @ J. M.'s ennui 's answer to the linked question) to then deal with it as a region? I tried `DiscretizeGraphics` but MMA told me `Option VertexNormals is not set in Options[Tube]`.

I tried to interpolate the points as per [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39444/interpolate-a-curve-in-3d)

```
pts = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}};
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];
```

but am struggling to find normal and binormal, even after looking [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt)

```
pts = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}};
r = Interpolation[Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];
t[t_] = Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals];
n[t_] = Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t \[Element] Reals];
bn[t_] = Simplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]], t \[Element] Reals];
```

Having said all of the above, it would ultimately be nice to be able to vary the thickness as easily as one does in `Tube[]` though.

Comment: `Tube[]` currently does not support `Texture[]`.

Comment: @J. M. Is it possible to feed it into `BoundaryMeshRegion[]` as in your previous answer to then deal with it as a region? I tried `DiscretizeGraphics` but MMA told me `Option VertexNormals is not set in Options[Tube]`

Comment: Like I said in my response in that other question, it's doable but not quite trivial. That's why I hadn't updated the answer in the other question yet.

Comment: @J. M. ah, please excuse my impatience! :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use new-in-12.1 directives ([`HalfToneShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfToneShading.html),[`ToonShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToonShading.html), [`GoochShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoochShading.html), [`StipleShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StipleShading.html)  etc) to texturize the surface of a `Tube` primitive:

```
Graphics3D[{HalftoneShading[Blue], CapForm[None], 
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}], {.2, .1, .1, .01}]},
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

We can use the function `surfaceAppearance` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240859/125) to control some shading parameters:

```
Graphics3D[{surfaceAppearance["Tiling" -> {5, 5}, 
   "FeatureColor" -> Blue, "UseScreenSpace" -> 1], CapForm[None], 
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}], {.2, .1, .1, .01}]},
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Use `surfaceAppearance["Tiling"->{3,3},"FeatureColor"->Blue,"UseScreenSpace"->1, "StepCount"->5,"LuminanceModifier"->0.1]` to get

[image]

**Update:**  It turns out, as of version 12.1, we can use `SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[img]]` to use `img` to texture `Tube` primitives:

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Graphics3D[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[lena]], 
  CapForm[None], 
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}],
    {.5, .1, .1, .01}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - will explore! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using @J. M.'s ennui 's `plotTube` function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169836/9923)

```
pts = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}};
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];
circ[u_, t_, v_] := v {Cos[u], Sin[u]} (1 - t);
plotTube[f[t], circ[u, t, .2], {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> {75, 45}]
```

[image]

Adding texture is now just a formality.

Comment: If you have a curve represented as a discrete set of points, instead of using a uniform parametrization like `Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)]`, I would instead recommend using [centripetal parametrization](https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1). Using `parametrizeCurve[]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898): `f = Interpolation[Transpose[{parametrizeCurve[pts], pts}]];`

Comment: @J. M. thank you for all the links, they are really helpful! :) Will have another go ..