# Evenly spaced points on boundary of polygon

Tags: random, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a polygon and I would like to generate $n$ evenly spaced points along the boundary.

Comment: Welcome! If you have already tried, please share your attempt with us, and it will be easier for us to help

Answer (score 11):

You can use piecewise linear interpolation:

Let's generate a random polygon:

```
R = ConvexHullMesh[RandomPoint[Disk[], 100]]
polygon = Append[#, #[[1]]] &@MeshCoordinates[R][[MeshCells[R, 2][[1, 1]]]];
```

[image]

Creating a piecewise-linear interpolation which is *parameterized by arc length*.

```
t = Prepend[Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences[polygon]], 0.];
γ = Interpolation[Transpose[{t, polygon}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True
   ];
```

Sampling it uniformly:

```
s = Subdivide[γ[[1, 1, 1]], γ[[1, 1, 2]], 100];
newpts = γ[s];
```

And plotting the generated points:

```
Show[
 R,
 ListPlot[newpts]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, chord-length parametrization. Sometimes I use it for [splines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10277)...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, and I also used your implementation frequently, e.g. to obtain smooth approximations to polygonal knots (application is e.g. mesh creation for Plateau problems). But here we want to follow the polygon exactly, so smoothing is actually unwanted.

Comment: Indeed, for applications that need piecewise-linear functions, chord length is still the simplest and best.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to generate a graphic, then you could use an [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow) with a custom [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads) directive. For example, here is a [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon) object:

```
poly = Polygon[{
    {7.361093855790543, 0.2777667989114292}, {8.37955832193947, 4.837661706721057},
    {8.064449639390588, 8.016729782194783}, {3.518023168010062, 8.74578450698846}, 
    {0.8343834304870779, 2.2170380309534554}, {4.807772222882807, 0.09815872747936005}, 
    {7.361093855790543, 0.2777667989114292}
}];

Graphics[RegionBoundary @ poly]
```

[image]

Show 10 evenly spaced points:

```
Graphics[{
    Arrowheads @ Append[
        ConstantArray[
            {.1, Automatic, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0,0}]}]},
            10
        ],
        0
    ],
    Arrow @@ RegionBoundary[poly]
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use  [`BSplineFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) and [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) with [`ArcLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html) as option value for the option [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html):

```
SeedRandom[77]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {7, 2}];
coords = pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]];
n = 10;

bsF = BSplineFunction[coords, SplineDegree -> 1];
ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> n, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large] , Point@bsF[0]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

We could also use mesh functions, as Vitaliy showed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84385/731):

```
plot = ListLinePlot[
   coords,
   Mesh -> 20,
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}
   ];
pts = Cases[Normal[plot], Point[pt_] :> pt, Infinity];
pts = Prepend[pts, First[coords]];

Graphics[{
  Line[coords],
  PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I reused the polygon in Carl's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the broad scheme of doing it would be as follows:

1. Load the Polytopes package:

   << Polytopes`
2. Use the vertices command (e.g. assuming that you are working with an octagon):

   a=Vertices[Octagon]
3. Set up a function which interpolates between two points using a parameter t.
4. Use the Map command to calculate the interpolated co-ordinates for any given value of t on successive values of your vertices.