# Plot a level curve and its gradient

Tags: plotting, vector, vector-calculus

Suppose that I have the following ellipse function,

$f(x,y)=4x^2+y^2-5$.

The gradient of this ellipse is calculated as

$\nabla f(x,y)=[8x,2y]$.

I know how to plot and join them. It is easy. I do the following,

```
P1 = ContourPlot[4 x^2 + y^2 == 5 , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
P2 = VectorPlot[{8 x, 2 y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
Show[P1, P2]
```

This gives me the following.

[image: ellipse function and its gradient]

But, What I would like to do is to see the gradient vectors only on the perimeter of my ellipse not everywhere. I tried to reduce the range of the variables in VectorPlot but it doesn't help. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Something like `P2 = VectorPlot[If[4 x^2 + y^2 <= 5, {8 x, 2 y}, {0, 0}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want it just on the outer surface of the ellipse, in other words on its perimeter

Comment: You could draw you own arrows like this:
`Show[Graphics[Table[Arrow[{{xPos[t], yPos[t]}, {xPos[t], yPos[t]} + .05 {8 xPos[t], 2 yPos[t]}}], {t,0, 2 Pi, .1}]], P1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180931) for creating [Evenly spaced points on boundary of polygon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180926), we can do this as follows:

```
f = {x, y} \[Function] 4 x^2 + y^2;
gradf = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]];
P1 = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];

numarrows = 100;

(*extracting the coordinates from the ContourPlot*)    
pts = Cases[P1, _GraphicsComplex, ∞][[1, 1]];

(*creating evenly distributed points on the ContourPlot (does only work for a single closed contour!)*)
t = Prepend[Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences[pts]], 0.];
γ = Interpolation[Transpose[{t, pts}], InterpolationOrder -> 1, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
s = Subdivide[γ[[1, 1, 1]], γ[[1, 1, 2]], numarrows];
newpts = γ[s];

(*plotting the scaled gradients*)
scale = 0.1;
P2 = Graphics[ Arrow[Most@Transpose[{newpts, newpts + scale gradf @@@ newpts}]]];

Show[P1, P2]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice answer with a very nice explanation. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In your `Cases[P1, _GraphicsComplex, All]` should the `All` be an `Infinity`?

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy Yeah maybe. As of version 11.3, `All` does also work.

Comment: Ah.  I work in 8.0 and 10.1.  Though the [online documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) doesn't seem to say it has that functionality yet.  Just the `Infinity` level specification.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[gradF, f]
gradF[f_] := Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> {##}] &; 
f[x_, y_] := 4 x^2 + y^2 -5
n = 100; length = .1; c = 0;
```

Use `"ArcLength"` as `MeshFunctions` and post-process points into arrows:

```
Normal[ContourPlot[f[x, y] == c , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   MeshFunctions -> { "ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 1 - 1/n, 1/n]}] ] /. 
 Point -> (Arrow[{#, # + length gradF[f] @@ #}] &)
```

[image]

Comment: This method does not work anymore at least since Mathematica 11.3. See this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241952/contourplot-and-meshfunctions-issue-between-versions-11-3-and-12-0). Is there any way to make this method work in the latest version of Mathematica? An alternative would be to extract the points (not spaced equidistant), make an interpolating parametric curve, and then use the same method with `ParametricPlot`.