# how to add gradient arrows in contourplot

Tags: plotting

There's a function z(x,y). Contourplot plots a 2D graph of z(x,y). How to put gradient arrows on top of contourplot? Better to use mathematica's embedded code.

Comment: related: [Plot a level curve and its gradient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182770/125)

Comment: no, i'm looking for a more direct approach, which doesn't require any definition of a separate gradient function

Comment: You might want to consider leveraging the `MeshFunctions` option of [`StreamDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamDensityPlot.html#108976196).

Comment: @yarchik no i need some easier command

Comment: Hi, it seems you find the linked example hard to understand and you would like an easier command. What would you like to simplify/explain? Since you explicitly ask for "arrows on top of contourplot", it seems impossible to avoid using `VectorPlot` and `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Silvia thanks this is quite good so far. but given a vector, it isn't able to generate its level curves all the time. when unable to generate, meshfunctions simply does nothing

Comment: @yarchik it's better for example to use contourplot to plot contour, meanwhile using some option UNDER contourplot to plot the gradient vectors on top of the contours