# ContourPlot and MeshFunctions issue between versions 11.3 and 12.0

Tags: plotting, mesh, version-12

### On Mathematica 11.3

This code produces the image below (a set of points that I am then using as a pattern for `FindRoot`):

```
IIges[x_, y_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2;
xm = 4;

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; 
ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
 ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]
```

[image]

### On Mathematica 12.0

The same code produces *nothing* ! **Why**??

[image]

Comment: You must change ContourStyle -> None for ContourStyle -> Automatic.

Comment: Still doesn't give me the same output as the 11.3 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
IIges[x_, y_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2;
xm = 4; {dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; 
ContourPlot[{dx[x, y], dy[x, y]} == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshFunctions -> {dx[#, #] &, dy[#, #] 
&}, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.009], GrayLevel[0.5]], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Small]]
```

[image]

Another way:

```
IIges[x_, y_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2;
xm = 4; {dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}];
ContourPlot[{dx[x, y], dy[x, y]} == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, dy[#1, #2] &}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.009], GrayLevel[0.5]], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Small]]
```

In the next page [MeshFunctions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html). Also try changing `MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, dy[#1, #2] &}` to `MeshFunctions -> {x, y, z, dy[x, y]}` and see the warning message it sends you.

Comment: This works, thanks. Do you have any idea why the "old" code doesn't return anything in Mathematica 12.0?

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work, but I will check the documentation. Greetings!

Comment: Documentation: "MeshFunctions in Mathematica 12 must be a pure function or a list of pure functions"

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link for that?

Comment: I added the link you requested and an additional comment. Greetings!

Comment: Yeah I also found that link, but where specifically do they say the thing about Mathemaica 12?

Comment: In the warnings.